# Polynomial Transformation Involving Mean

Tags: statistics, polynomials, transformation

I was reading a book on statistics and I found that the following must hold. I tested it in Mathematica for n up to 5 and it passes that test (btw it has nothing to do with stats anymore, only polynomials. For anybody into statistics this is the variance of the x's):

For $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ reals

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-a)^2=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i,j=1}^n(x_i-x_j)^2
$$

where $a$ is just the average of the x's,

$$
a=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k
$$

Any ideas fellas?

Comment: Hmmm I've got a great idea!  But you're not including me as a possible source of great ideas.

Comment: Have a look here at the pdf on page 2: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yuli_Zhang/publication/261496020_Some_new_deformation_formulas_about_variance_and_covariance/links/54eda4c80cf25da9f7f1274e/Some-new-deformation-formulas-about-variance-and-covariance.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Write $(x_i-x_j)$ as $(x_i-a)+(a-x_j)$ and expand the lhs. The rest is straight forward.

Comment: good one! Didn't think it would be so simple..